# Excel VBA hidden list columns shift

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a weird issue with hidden columns. It only seems to happen when they are hidden in code, not manually.
Given this:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
1       A       3       1
1       B       3       2
1       C       3       3
```

If I write

```
lcTableCols = ListObjects("Table1").listcolumns
lcTableCols("ColC").Range.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

that column will be hidden, but if I then add a column or delete a column to the left:

```
lcTableCols("ColB").Delete
```

The hidden column "shifts" so now the table looks like this:

```
ColA    ColC
1       3       
1       3       
1       3
```

With ColD now hidden. It only does this with list columns. Doing the following works as expected:

```
Columns(5).hidden = true
Columns(3).delete
```

I can only assume it has something to do with the ".Range.EntireColumn". What is the better way? I want the function to be able to hide named columns, and I know I could do it another way (lcTableCol("ColE").index) but I'm formatting a large sheet and would need to refactor a lot. Not a huge issue, but I'm curious why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hiding an `EntireColumn` (`C`), Then removing a column (colD) from the table only, not from  the worksheet. This is ambiguous, the deletion just shifts the columns of the table but Excel is obliged to keep the "entire Column" because it might have other data outside the table!

If you delete also by `EntireColumn` the behavior is as expected:

```
lcTableCols("ColC").Range.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
lcTableCols("ColB").Range.EntireColumn.Delete
```

Here you will have only columns `A` and `D`.

Comment: I see! Okay. I guess this is in case you have multiple tables under or next too each other?

Comment: @Daniel For example. Actually any data that is on the same column of the one removed *from the table* has to stay. Therefore, actually, the operation is equivalent to removing a range of "cells" from the worksheet. everything to the right of these cells gets shifted to the left.

Comment: And since Excel cannot hide individual cells, but entire columns or rows, the shifted cells come to a visible column and will be visible.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense! I redid the delete column formula to delete whole columns instead of table columns.